# From where or How can I download Cloudera Quick start VM 5.12

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

In the cloudera website I can see only the Cloudera Quick start VM 5.13.But I need Quick start VM 5.12.

From where or How can I download Quick start VM 5.12

Answer (score 0):

The [official website](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-13.html) states:

> The current Quickstart VM is based on CDH 5.13. Although Cloudera
>   periodically releases updated versions with newer releases of CDH,
>   older versions are not available for download.

So you can't download 5.12, at least from official site.